# Register functions without using them "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, luainterface, nlua

I have an IRC Bot in C# and I want to use Lua Scripting for the moment. On bot startup I want to register functions, and detect if a new file has been added then load it. I did the new file / reload scripts function already, but when I hit run I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on a custom function I want users to be able to use.

Here's the current code:

```
public Lua lua;
public void RegisterFunctions() {
    lua.RegisterFunction("print", this, typeof(DashLua).GetMethod("ConsoleOut"));
}
#region Custom Functions for Lua
public void ConsoleOut(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Script error: print() can't be null.");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

In the Main() of the bot I have just 2 lines currently:

```
    DashLua dash = new DashLua();
    dash.RegisterFunctions();
```

Comment: Are you initializing the `lua` field? It would help to know whether the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Have to use `public Lua lua;` instead of `public Lua lua = new Lua();` in order to initialize the field. Since I've already initialized it in the "Lua.cs" file and I'm calling the DashLua class to my main class, there is no point to initialize it in the Main() void currently.

Comment: Another way to put it if I do something like this: `public void RegisterFunctions() {
 lua = new Lua();
 lua.RegisterFunction("print", typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(String) }));}` I will get this error: **Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLua (NuGet) only works on x64 builds which is why none of this actually worked. So if you're building a project and really need a Lua as a scripting language, you need to change your build to x64 in the Project's properties. That being said, you can get the Win32 version at their website which is a shame it's not on nuget.

**EDIT:** When you go and download the Win32 build, it's empty. I guess they have not built it and encourage you to build it yourself.

Comment: NLua.Win32 build was fixed, you can grab the .zip now. I am working on 1.3.1 version I will update the NuGet package ASAP.